# Function to estimate area under the curve for different parametric distributions without manually changing values in R

Tags: r, distribution

The problem is to estimate probability density area under some parametric continuous distribution between some discrete values (i.e. (F(x+1) - F(x)). Thus, a quick way to do it in R would be, as follow (with pchisq as an example):

```
 size <- 20
 vector<-0; sequence<-seq(0, size, by=1) 
 for (i in 1:length(sequence)) vector[i] <- pchisq(min[i+1], 5) - pchisq(min[i],   5)
 vector <- vector[-length(vector)]
```

However, if I want to change the distribution, it is necessary to manually change the name of distribution, values of parameters, and the number of parameters.

How would it be possible to do it automatically. Let just say, it may look like:

```
 func <- function(size, "distribution", "vectors of theta") {
 vector<-0; sequence<-seq(0, size, by=1) 
 for (i in 1:length(min)) sequence[i] <- "distribution"(min[i+1], "theta[1]", "theta[ n]") - pchisq(min[i],   "theta[1]", "theta[n]")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to use `switch` . I know some folks think that's clunky, but it does allow you to select the function (distribution) of your choice and apply the appropriate collection of parameters to each possible function.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
dist = pchisq
```

or whatever distribution function you want, then use your first block of code with dist instead of the specific distribution function.

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful. However, may I ask how to add not only name of distribution, but also how to adjust for the number of parameters in a function? That is, in the function I may have separate name "dist" for distribution, and "theta" for parameters. If I have different number of parameters of distribution, I have to go inside into the function and change it manually. How to avoid it?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're going for, but hopefully an example will help. Suppose you wanted to use a t-distribution and fix df at 10. Then create the function

dist = function(x) pt(x, df = 10)

and use that in your calculations.

Comment: Thank you. Let me clarify, e.g. I do have a function: a<-function(dist, theta1, size){    
  vector<-0; sequence<-seq(0, size, by=1) 
  for (i in 1:length(sequence)) vector[i] <- dist(min[i+1],theta1) - dist(min[i],theta1)
  vector <- vector[-length(vector)]
  vector1 <- vector/sum(vector)
  return(vector1)
}
That means, if I want to apply t distribution, then it is fine. On the other, if I want to apply distribution with two parameters, once again I have adjust the whole function (add par2 not only in the begging of the function, but also inside it). How to deal with it?

Comment: Ah, I understand. It looks like your parameters are constant in your calculations, so you want a function that accepts only quantiles. To do this, you can use (using the beta distribution as an example `dist <- function(x) pbeta(x, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 4)` or whatever parameter values you want.

Comment: Thank you again. But somehow I do not see how it solves the problem. I do need to implement the function like as follow: IF distributions has 2 parameters, then functions acts in one way, while ELSE it has 1 parameter, function does not pay attention to one of the parameters written inside the function. Maybe switch, as suggested above, may help to solve it.